# SQL add extra field on group by query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a working query to extract the minimum time of every athlete in every distance in the table "Tempi". These is a simple group by query , grouping the results by athleteID and distanceID and selecting the Minimum time. But I need now to know where and when this times are obtained. This data are in another table named "Manif". The  two tables are joined by the ManifID, present in both tables. How can I retrieve the date and the city of the time?
Thanks!

Working query

```
SELECT 
    [02_tEMPI].CodSpec, 
    [04_Spec].DescrSpecShort, 
    Min([02_Tempi].Tempo) AS MinDiTempo
FROM  
    [04_Spec] 
    INNER JOIN [03_Manif] 
    INNER JOIN [02_Tempi] 
        ON [03_Manif].IDManif = [02_Tempi].CodManif 
        ON [04_Spec].CodSpec = [02_Tempi].CodSpec
WHERE 
    [02_Tempi].CodAtleta=@CodAtleta AND 
    [03_Manif].Base = @Base 
GROUP BY 
    [04_Spec].DescrSpecShort,
    [02_Tempi].CodSpec
HAVING 
    [02_Tempi].CodSpec <'60'
ORDER BY 
    [02_Tempi].CodSpec
```

Tempi Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[02_Tempi] (
    [IDRisu]            BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    [CodAtleta]         VARCHAR (12) NULL,
    [CodSpec]           VARCHAR (4)  NULL,
    [CodManif]          INT          NULL,
    [Note]              VARCHAR (14) NULL,
    [CodSocContingente] VARCHAR (14) NULL,
    [Cat]               VARCHAR (5)  NULL,
    [CatFIN]            VARCHAR (4)  NULL,
    [CatPrimato]        INT          NULL,
    [Elaborato]         SMALLINT     NULL,
    [Tempo]             VARCHAR (8)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK__02_Tempi] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDRisu] ASC)
```

mANIF TABLE STRUCTURE

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[03_Manif] (
    [IDManif]    INT           NOT NULL,
    [DescrManif] VARCHAR (100) NULL,
    [LuogoManif] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [Base]       SMALLINT      NULL,
    [LinkPDF]    VARCHAR (250) NULL,
    [Data]       VARCHAR (10)  NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK__03_Manif] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IDManif] ASC)
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Dario, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed first question, and for including so much of the relevant information in this post.  Can you please edit your question to indicate the RDBMS and version (e.g., SQL Server 2012, MySQL, Oracle 9, etc.)  of your database?  Several of the best possible approaches are version-specific.  To edit, look for the word 'edit' in gray near the bottom of your post.

Comment: added `sql-server` tag based on the syntax provided

Comment: I noticed CodSpec is varchar, so as warning the comparison < '60' might not work as you assume, since '100' would match that, and '9' would not, because the comparison is done in alphabetical order, not as numeric.

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for the info. CodSpec is always a 2-digit numeric string, starting from '00' to '84'.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this `row_number` window function:

```
;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [04_Spec].DescrSpecShort,
                                [02_Tempi].CodSpec ORDER BY [02_Tempi].Tempo ) AS rn
               FROM     [04_Spec]
                        INNER JOIN [02_Tempi] ON [04_Spec].CodSpec = [02_Tempi].CodSpec
                        INNER JOIN [03_Manif] ON [03_Manif].IDManif = [02_Tempi].CodManif
               WHERE    [02_Tempi].CodAtleta = @CodAtleta
                        AND [03_Manif].Base = @Base
                        AND [02_Tempi].CodSpec < '60'
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi Giorgi. Thanks for the solution. I've got this error: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The column 'CodSpec' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.

Comment: Inside cte, replace `*` with column names and alias them. Subquery can not return multiple columns with same name.

Answer (score 0):

A potential approach

- Select your minimum time, grouped by athleteID and distanceID
- Cross apply that result back to the Tempi table on those 3 fields to get the ManifID from the original Tempi record (using SELECT 1 with some order if it is possible for that to have more than 1 result).
- Using that ManifID to join with your Manif table.

  ```
  SELECT 
      Min(T1.Tempo) [Fastest Tempo],
      T1.AthleteID, 
      T1.DistanceID,
      SUBT.ManifID
  FROM [02_Tempi] T1
  CROSS APPLY
      (
          SELECT TOP 1 T2.ManifID
          FROM [02_Tempi] T2
          WHERE T2.AthleteID = T1.AthleteID
              AND T2.DistanceID = T1.DistanceID
          ORDER BY T2.Tempo DESC --add other differentiating columns if necessary
      ) SUBT
  JOIN [03_Manif] M
      ON SUBT1.ManifID = M.ManifID
  GROUP BY 
      T1.AthleteID, 
      T1.DistanceID,
      SUBT.ManifID
  ```